# SpringData JPA Transaction management

Tags: jpa, transactions

please help me about Spring JPA Transaction Management
I have two methods: usersService.addUser and authoritiesService.addNew

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = PROPAGATION.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
public class UsersService {

@Autowired
UsersRepository usersRepository;

@Autowired
AuthotitiesRepository authoritiesReposotory;

@Transaction
public addUser(...){
   usersRespository.addUser...
   authoritiesRepository.addNew...
}
...

public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {
   @Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query(value = "insert into users..."
}

public interface AuthoritiesRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {
   @Transactional
   @Modifying
   @Query(value = "insert into abc ...."
}
```

The problem is when authoritiesRepository.addNew throws Exception(by some SQL syntax) I want to automatically rollback user info.

How can I configure in repository, service ?

**Here is the exception trace:**

2019-05-22 08:33:16.185  WARN 2276 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2019-05-22 08:33:16.185 ERROR 2276 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "AUTHORITIESS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into authoritiess(username, authority) values(?, ?) [42102-199]
2019-05-22 08:33:16.220 ERROR 2276 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by commit exception

com.springboot.example.exception.DbCRUDException: Error on add user 
    at com.springboot.example.security.service.UsersService.addUser(UsersService.java:141) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springboot.example.security.service.UsersService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3d37fb4e.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: com.springboot.example.exception.DbCRUDException: Error on add authority 
    at com.springboot.example.security.service.AuthoritiesService.addNew(AuthoritiesService.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.springboot.example.security.service.UsersService.addUser(UsersService.java:139) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into authoritiess(username, authority) values(?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:256) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[sprin
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "AUTHORITIESS" not found; SQL statement:
**insert into authoritiess(username, authority) values(?, ?)** [42102-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
2019-05-22 08:33:16.226 ERROR 2276 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only] with root cause

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:

Comment: What is your problem with current approach?

Answer (score 0):

As @thanhngo alread mentioned. This is how to do it.

You already have the correct annotation on the `addUser` method and any `RuntimeException` will cause the transaction to be rolled back.

Make sure that `usersRespository.addUser...` and `authoritiesReposotory.addNew...` also have the `@Transactional` annotation

Comment: I did.But it is still not work.I am using SpringBoot and Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Can you please post the exception stacktrace you get?

Comment: I posted exception trace.

Comment: Are you sure that the table name is AUTHORITIESS not AUTHORITIES?

Comment: I tried to change table name from AUTHORITIES to AUTHORITIESS for testing rollback transaction.

Comment: But thanks you, I found the problem, I missed one Transactional anotation on a method in services class.